# A basis for formal laurent series

Tags: abstract-algebra, laurent-series, formal-power-series

I was looking for a countable $A$-shauder's basis for the Laurent formal series in two variables
$ \mathbb{C}[[t,s]][(ts)^{-1}]$. $A=\mathbb{C}[[t-s]]$. For example $\{t^ns^n, t^{n+1}s^n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} $ but if I would see the expansion of a generic element in this basis there is a typical way? I've just tried with a combinatorial method but it's not satisfactory but sufficent

Comment: Anything unclear in my answer?

Comment: No,sorry, but my question it wasn't about an example of basis but an example of way to find the coefficient

Comment: I think it is your question. Your basis is wrong, it is a ring it contains every powers of $ts^{-1}$. And "finding coefficients" it depends how you define your element of the ring.

Comment: My basis is right, but $(ts)^{-1}$

Comment: Still not right $\mathbb{C}[[t,s]][(ts)^{-1}]$ contains every power of $(ts)^{-1}$ whence every monomial $t^i s^j$.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry again, I've edited the question, I've forgotten a little detail but I didn't review the question. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The natural Schauder basis of $$\mathbb{C}[[t,s]][(ts)^{-1}]$$ is $$\{s^i t^j\}_{i,j\in \Bbb{Z} }$$
And $$ \sum_{i,j\in \Bbb{Z}} c_{i,j}s^i t^j \in \mathbb{C}[[t,s]][(ts)^{-1}]$$ iff there is $M$ such that $c_{i,j}=0$ for $\min(i,j)<M$.